# Air Bag Warning Light On in 2002 Golf TDI GLS

Tags: vw, golf, supplemental-restraint-system

My air bag warning light has been on for a month now. Is this cause for concern regarding safety? What is the likelihood of it going off randomly? From the research I have done it seems it is likely just an issue with the electrical connection. Can anyone confirm this. The dealership said they charge $200 just to evaluate it. I cannot afford this. I am hoping to fix this myself if at all possible and am looking for a step by step if anyone knows how/has done this themselves.

Thanks in advance,

Brad

Comment: An airbag light can be dangerous because it could mean a broken airbag or malfunctioning. if you dont know airbags are "explosives" and can be very dangerous. Dealerships are always expensive so why not try a cheaper mechanic locally? Or if you have experience fixing cars you can ofcourse do it yourself just remember to unplug the battery for 20/30 min before doing anything with the airbag.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the car is a 2002 Golf, my vehicle specific advice is to check that the connectors under the seats, in particular the front passenger seat, are fully engaged in their connectors.  This is a very common problem on these cars.

If you can get ahold of a piece of software called VCDS you can read the fault codes and reset the light yourself.  Various versions are available from the RossTech website including a free-ware one which, on your car, will allow you to do everything you need.

Comment: I'm not sure about this car in particular, but some cars _require_ the fault codes to be cleared even after the fault is corrected.  I was messing around with the radio on a 2010 Tiguan and unplugged the passenger airbag warning light and that set a code.  The airbag system continued to show a warning even after it was plugged back in until I got around to clearing it.

Comment: Yes, VCDS allows the fault to be cleared.